# Hide and show columns in an HTML table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**[Codepen Link](http://codepen.io/knitevision1/pen/wBYWQd)**

I've tried to Google, but there's no library that has an API to toggle table columns when clicked elsewhere on the page, so I've decided to do this:

```
function deleteColumnOnClick() {

    $('.hide div').click(function() {
        var index = $(this).index();
        $('table thead th').eq(index).toggleClass('hidden');
        var hidden = $('table thead th.hidden')
        $.each(hidden, function() {
            var idx = $(this).index();
            $.each($('table tbody tr'), function() {
                $(this).find('td').eq(idx).hide();
            });
        });

        var visible = $('table thead th:not(.hidden)');
        $.each(visible, function() {
            var idx = $(this).index();
            $.each($('table tbody tr'), function() {
                $(this).find('td').eq(idx).show();
            });                    
        });
    });
}



deleteColumnOnClick();
```

Is this an awful solution? If yes, how do I refactor it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right now, the relationship between the hide/show "buttons" and the columns is pretty fragile. You're dependent on the buttons being in the same exact order as the columns. If you add or remove a button, the indices stop making sense; you can't rely on the 3rd button always being linked to the 3rd column and vice versa.

I'd suggest giving the buttons (or whatever element you use to hide/show columns) a `data-column` attribute or something similar to make it explicit that *this* button controls *that* column. Similarly, the `th` cells can carry a `data-column` attribute or simply an ID to identify them.

For instance:

```
<button type="button" data-column="#column-abc">Hide/show</button>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th id="column-foo">A column</th>
      <th id="column-xzy">Another column</th>
      <th id="column-abc">Yet another column</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  ...
```

Now it's explicit that the button will hide column `#column-abc`. And it'll simplify the code too, since relationships between things are no longer just assumed or implied.

Secondly, you're (in a sense) trying to both hide and show the column, and just seeing what works. It'd be simpler to just do a `hasClass("hidden")` check. There are also some jQuery selector magic you can use.

Something like this, for instance:

```
// global click handler for any element with a "data-column" attribute
$("[data-column]").on("click", function () {
  var button = $(this),                   // the element that was clicked
      header = $(button.data("column")),  // the cell referenced by the button
      table = header.closest("table"),    // the table in which the cell resides
      index = header.index() + 1,         // convert to CSS's 1-based indexing
      selector = "tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")",  // selector for all body cells in the column 
      column = table.find(selector).add(header); // all cells in the column

  // toggle the "hidden" class on all the column cells
  column.toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vc17995o/1/)

Comment: Thats beautiful! Way more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 0):

if you want multiple columns to hide, here is the code. i just modified Flambino's code.

```
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="column-a">A column</th>
  <th class="column-a">Another column will hide with A</th>
  <th class="column-b">Yet another column</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<button type="button" data-column=".column-a" style="width:45%;float:left">Combination 2</button>
<button type="button" data-column=".column-b" style="width:45%;float:left">Combination 3</button>


$(document).on("click", "[data-column]", function () {           
        var button = $(this),
            header = $(button.data("column")),
            table = header.closest("table");

        for (var i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {                
          var index = header.index() + i + 1, 
          selector = "tbody tr td:nth-child(" + index + ")",
          column = table.find(selector).add(header[i]);
          column.toggleClass("hidden");
        }         
    });
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! You have presented an alternative solution, but haven't reviewed the code. Please [edit] to show what aspects of the question code prompted you to write this version, and in what ways it's an improvement over the original.  It may be worth (re-)reading [answer].